# Pass parameters for only one modal wiht UIkit

Tags: javascript, getuikit

I'm using [UIkit(2.27.2)](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/modal.html) mainly to manage modals.

And I would like to edit the default labels button of a confirm dialog

So I used the following

```
UIkit.modal.confirm('My text here', 
        function(){ //Click ok } ,
        function(){ //Click cancel } ,
        {
            labels: {
                "Cancel": 'No, let me check a last time',
                "Ok": 'Ok, I want to store the final result'
            }
        }
    );
```

And it's working fine.

The problem is that once I used that, all my others modals have also thoses buttons! And I don't want that.

How to pass parameters for only one modal?
I tried to add this code juste after my modal but it's not "proper".

```
UIkit.modal.confirm('', 
        function(){ } ,
        function(){  } ,
        {
            labels: {
                "Cancel": 'Cancel',
                "Ok": 'Ok'
            }
        }
    ).remove();
```

After this, all the others modals are fine, and only the one selected have custom labels. But a "blank" modal is appearing, the `.remove()` does not seems working well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like this answer but since it's the only one that I found... it may help other people.

So, after the declaration of my modal with special labels I used this code

```
var modal = UIkit.modal.confirm('', 
    function(){ } ,
    function(){ } ,
        {
            labels: {
            "Cancel": 'Cancel',
            "Ok": 'Ok'
            }
        }
);

if ( modal.isActive() ) {
    modal.hide();
}
```